# Meteor-upload cannot read property 'contentType' of undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor

I literally followed the tutorial line for line on https://github.com/tomitrescak/meteor-uploads and I get a 503 Service Unavailable right after the upload reaches 100%. The js console log says /upload is missing but I don't know what that means

```
 render.change file: IMG_4180.JPG
uploader.js:167 render.add 
jquery.js:9659 POST http://treehacks.cloudapp.net:3000/upload 503 (Service Unavailable)
uploader.js:200 render.fail 
uploader.js:82 data.sumbit.fail: Unexpected error. 503 Service Unavailable
uploader.js:85 data.sumbit.always:  textStatus= error
sockjs-0.3.4.js:854 GET http://treehacks.cloudapp.net:3000/sockjs/info?cb=on9gi8aoej 503 (Service Unavailable)
sockjs-0.3.4.js:854 GET http://treehacks.cloudapp.net:3000/sockjs/info?cb=esmeje0lui 503 (Service Unavailable)
sockjs-0.3.4.js:854 GET http://treehacks.cloudapp.net:3000/sockjs/info?cb=us0wyblu2e 503 (Service Unavailable)
```

Simultaneously, the server crashes and only serves error pages afterwards. On  the server log, I get

```
W20150222-01:49:32.150(0)? (STDERR) app/meteor.js:57
W20150222-01:49:32.159(0)? (STDERR)           return formData.contentType;
W20150222-01:49:32.159(0)? (STDERR)                          ^
W20150222-01:49:32.264(0)? (STDERR) TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentType' of undefined
W20150222-01:49:32.275(0)? (STDERR)     at Object.UploadServer.init.getDirectory (app/meteor.js:57:23)
W20150222-01:49:32.275(0)? (STDERR)     at IncomingForm.<anonymous> (packages/tomi:upload-server/upload_server.js:326:1)
W20150222-01:49:32.275(0)? (STDERR)     at IncomingForm.emit (events.js:98:17)
W20150222-01:49:32.275(0)? (STDERR)     at /home/treehacks/.meteor/packages/tomi_upload-server/.1.2.1.uqdd2s++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:228:12
W20150222-01:49:32.276(0)? (STDERR)     at WriteStream.<anonymous> (/home/treehacks/.meteor/packages/tomi_upload-server/.1.2.1.uqdd2s++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/formidable/lib/file.js:70:5)
W20150222-01:49:32.276(0)? (STDERR)     at WriteStream.g (events.js:180:16)
W20150222-01:49:32.276(0)? (STDERR)     at WriteStream.emit (events.js:117:20)
W20150222-01:49:32.284(0)? (STDERR)     at finishMaybe (_stream_writable.js:359:12)
W20150222-01:49:32.286(0)? (STDERR)     at afterWrite (_stream_writable.js:279:5)
W20150222-01:49:32.286(0)? (STDERR)     at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:269:7)
W20150222-01:49:32.286(0)? (STDERR)     at WritableState.onwrite (_stream_writable.js:96:5)
```

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. Anyone have any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: For me `{{> dropzone contentType='images' fileTypes='.jpg' multiple=true formData=specificFormData }}` is working fine but having troubles with `{{> upload_bootstrap}}`